# Can I install new construction lights into old ceiling with attic vs remodel lights?

Tags: light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I want to put in can lights throughout my house. I have attic space to do it and from what I have read it seems like the new construction lights are better than the remodel lights that appear to put all the weight on the drywall ceiling. Any advice on this?

Comment: It really helps to lay down planks so it isn't just joists and drywall keeping you from falling through the ceiling.  Also, work in the early mornings *before* the heat of the day has turned your attic into an oven.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about the "extra weight".  The are aluminum (or other lightweight metal) and that's not a big concern.  Use the remodel lights - much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the space above (or in the case where you are ripping off & replacing the sheetrock from below, even if that's not your case) you should be able to use "new construction" style can lights, yes.

It may involve hot, filthy work in the attic space, and depending where you want the lights and the configuration of the attic, it may be a tight squeeze (or there may be plenty of room - attic spaces vary, a lot.) Depending on your type of insulation, you might be well advised to wear a coverall suit, gloves and a respirator and/or goggles when working up there, which will make it hotter, so beware of getting overheated (passing out in an attic is not a great idea...)

With advancements in LED technology, surface-mount "can style" lights are also a recent option. Look like a can-light trim ring, but don't require a can above them.

Comment: Is there a benefit to having new construction lights? They just seem superior installed than remodel. I got the impression the surface mount lights are a lower quality. I could be wrong. I am looking to have quality dimmers and led bulbs i can replace not the type that is all one light. It is hard to know what the right thing to do is, and I don't want to find out after I've paid a company $1000s to have lights installed throughout the house.

Comment: A matter of opinion, and what you get. There's cheap crap in every sort of package, and better stuff as well. If the drywall does not get wet, it should have no trouble supporting a remodel-style light.  In my opinion, LED bulbs (rather than LED fixtures, designed as LED fixtures from the ground up, if they are designed properly) are dubious, as many thermal compromises have to be made to package an LED light into a form-factor suited to 19th century incandescent bulbs. But you can find badly designed and constructed LED fixtures quite easily. Likewise LED bulbs.

Comment: Oh, you're _paying_ someone to install lights?  Then you really don't want new construction.  The will most likely charge you a lot more for having to work in a hot attic.